# Puppet master: how to turn on logging?

Tags: puppet

We have FOSS Puppet 3.8.1 running a master and at some point it started responding 500 to our clients at their request for catalog.

Having absolutely no idea what's wrong, I started searching for some logs and found nothing.

`/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` on master looks like

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=/lib/facter
pluginsync=true

[agent]
server=our-app.com
certname=cert-name
```

There is a `/var/log/puppet folder`, but it is empty.

Can someone help with finding where the errors are logged?

Comment: Are you using puppet-server or the old ruby puppet-master? Depending on your platform, your puppet-master might only be logging to /var/log/messages. This might help: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/services_master_rack.html#logging

Comment: Probably they're logged to `/var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 1):

On the puppetmaster, run this command

```
puppet config print |grep log
```

On my system this comes up with various useful looking paths like

```
masterhttplog = /var/log/puppet/masterhttp.log
httplog = /var/log/puppet/http.log
railslog = /var/log/puppet/rails.log
masterlog = /var/log/puppet/puppetmaster.log
puppetdlog = /var/log/puppet/puppetd.log
```

also for debugging the relationship of the puppetmaster and agents and for errors in manifest files the reports are useful

```
puppet config print |grep report
```

Note that the puppetmaster itself can also be a agent so there could well be stuff like a `last_run_report.yaml` which is concerning the puppetmaster configuring itself, but you maybe want to skip these

Comment: Thanks! But here is the thing: it says there should be logs under /var/log/puppet/, but there is just masterhttp.log. So how come there are no other logs? Maybe it's about log level?

Comment: It turns out that `masterlog` option has actually never been used and as a matter of fact it has been removed see -https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-877

Comment: please note: puppet often change their paths, the cli and the internals.  This answer was correct 2 years ago.  Treat with caution!

Answer (score 0):

On redhat clones at least, the logging is configured in `/etc/sysconfig/puppet`:

```
PUPPET_LOG=/var/log/puppet/puppet.log
```

or

```
PUPPET_LOG=syslog
```

If you select syslog it will send the messages to `/dev/log`, from where they are picked up by your logging daemon (rsyslog), which will write the lines most probably in `/var/log/messages`.

The simplest way is to use a file instead of syslog.